# Issue with debugging: perspective won't open

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a program and I broke something, so I'm trying to debug it, but the debug perspective window won't open. I'm not sure how to fix this at all.

I've gone through a lot of the setting revolving around the Debug/Run, but I don't want to mess too many things up. I can't seem to find a way to change settings I initialised.

If I can't fix the debug, the code I've broken is the default constructor I've done. I have data as a private double array (private double[] data) and the  code for the constructor is:

```
`public Stat (double[] d){ 
        if(d.length == 0) {
            data = new double[0];
        }else
            for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                d[i] = data[i];

            }`
```

This is meant to take an array and copy it to data, but the problem occurs in the last line, and I'm not sure why. The corresponding line in the test file is:
        stat1 = new Stat(data);
data is a double array that was initialised previously.

The output follows after stat1 goes through other methods, however at this point, stat1 is just supposed to equal data. Like the values in data are copied to stat1 so they can be manipulated.

Comment: hmm you probably dismissed the box asking to open the debug perspective. Right click on the Debug perspective icon on the top right and select 'reset'.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a ton!